# Simulating 'RSSI for LTE network' in matlab

Tags: matlab, lte

The Definition of RSSI is 'Total received wide-band power by UE'

1. I have confusion in understanding that what is meant by wide-band here.
   My understanding is as follows

> a. In case if Carrier Bandwidth of LTE channel is 10 MHz,total
>   bandwidth is 10 MHz and hence RSSI is calculated for all the all the
>   Resource blocks i.e. 50 RB
>
> b. Each RB has 12 subcarriers. Hence for 10 MHz channel, 50 RB are
>   dedicated => 12x50 = 60 subchannels
>
> c. Finally (Assuming same Pt for all subcarrier) Pr =
>   Pt*(c/4*pi*d*F*)2 . What is the F should I put and is this the right
>   way to calculate the Pr? In my opinions F = 15KhZ. Where Pr is
>   Received Power per subcarrier by UE. (Using
>
> d. Finally RSSI = Pr*12*50  [ or dBm 10*log10(Pr) + 10*log10(12*50)]

2. Or RSSI is calculated in any different way in simulation / How can I make simulation model to calculate RSSI. Do I have to make a model with a complete RB with all Resource Elements (RE). If yes, then do I need to do the scheduling as well?
3. How can I calculate SINR with RSSI?

Thanks

Shan

Comment: You should specify your environment a bit better with additional info (and maybe tags). Is this simulink? Or some specific toolbox?

Comment: It is Matlab (mentioned in the tags). I am not using any toolbox since I am developing my own simulator and other constraints!

Comment: Simulink *is* MATLAB, that's why I was asking. If you're not using any special MATLAB-related tools, then your question is very unclear. This is a site for programming, and your question sounds like something from en electrical engineering textbook. While some users might understand the concepts you're asking about (including stuff such as RSSI and SINR and RB), you'll probably find it very hard to find an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. RSSI is computed taking a power density integrated over the bandwidth of interest. So for the same average power density, 5 MHz LTE versus 10 MHz LTE will have a 3dB difference in RSSI.
2. RSSI will vary with data/control traffic as well since it considers all subcarriers. So yes, what the scheduler is doing matters.
3. RSSI alone is insufficient to compute SINR. You will need RSRP as well. (or a derived quantity like RSRQ)